# How can i get to xml attribute of <yt:accesscontrol>?

Tags: php, xml, youtube, simplexml, xml-namespaces

I can't figure out or find out how to parse the `permission="allowed"` value out of this xml, using PHP `simplexml_load_file`.

the basic structure is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" gd:etag="W/&quot;DkEDSH47eCp7I2A9WhJbEEQ.&quot;">
<yt:accessControl action="comment" permission="allowed" />
<yt:accessControl action="commentVote" permission="allowed" />
<yt:accessControl action="videoRespond" permission="moderated" />
<yt:accessControl action="rate" permission="allowed" />
<yt:accessControl action="embed" permission="allowed" />
<yt:accessControl action="list" permission="allowed" />
<yt:accessControl action="autoPlay" permission="allowed" />
<yt:accessControl action="syndicate" permission="allowed" />
```

How can get to the value of the `permission=allowed` attribute on that last line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was so annoying to figure out...

(where `$xml = simplexml_load_file($source);` )

I'm able to get to the permission attribute with:

```
$xml->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007')->accessControl[4]->attributes()->permission;
```

Comment: I think it's just to get into the know that there are namespaces in XML and that SimpleXMLElement supports those. Another way to obtain these is by specifying the namespace when you call `simplexml_load_file` btw., see [*What are the “$ns” and “$is_prefix” parameters about?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17258883/367456) and as well [*difference between getDocNamespaces and getNamespaces in SimpleXML*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18351002/367456).

Answer (score 2):

You want to use **XPath** to retrieve records, it's an XML query language.

Please see the [SimpleXMLElement's xpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) and [registerXPathNamespace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.registerxpathnamespace.php) methods.
W3Schools explains [XPath's syntax here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

For this XML

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<book xmlns:chap="http://example.org/chapter-title">
   <title>My Book</title>
</book>
EOD;
```

you'd register a namespace like this:

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('c', 'http://example.org/chapter-title');
$result = $sxe->xpath('//c:title');
```