# What are the "$ns" and "$is_prefix" parameters about?

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

The [`SimpleXMLElement::__construct()` method](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.__construct) and the related functions [`simplexml_load_string()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_string) and [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) all have an optional pair of parameters related to XML Namepspaces: `$ns` and `$is_prefix`.

Despite I can see that those are related to XML namespaces I wonder what they are for and how they work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to PHP manual, those two parameters have been added in PHP version 5.2. The official PHP 5 changelog does not note these changes explicitly but [the PHP 5.2 update readme has these](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_2/README.UPDATE_5_2#942).

Then looking into the 5.2 source for the constructor ([in lxr](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_2/ext/simplexml/simplexml.c#2095)) it shows that this is related to the iterator:

> ```
> sxe->iter.nsprefix = ns_len ? xmlStrdup((xmlChar *)ns) : NULL;
> sxe->iter.isprefix = isprefix;
> ```

So I assume those two specify the XML Namespace that *`SimpleXMLElement`* will iterate over *by default*. A little test can verify this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
    '<root><a/><b/><c/></root>'
);

var_dump(count(iterator_to_array($xml))); #int(3)
```

By default, the iterator has three elements here: a, b and c. Now setting the parameters specifying the iteration to be over a different XML-Namespace than the default one changes this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
    '<root><a/><b/><c/></root>', 0, FALSE, "ns:1"
);

var_dump(count(iterator_to_array($xml))); #int(0)
```

The iteration now has zero elements because the root-element does not have any child-elements in the namespace of URI `ns:1`.

Changing the namespace of the root element to `ns:1` will again reveal three elements because now those three child-elements are in that namespace, they inherit it from their parent:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
    '<root xmlns="ns:1"><a/><b/><c/></root>', 0, FALSE, "ns:1"
);

var_dump(count(iterator_to_array($xml))); #int(3)
```

Same as if the children itself are in the namespace specified by that parameter pair and via a prefix on these elements:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
    '<root xmlns:n="ns:1"><n:a/><n:b/><n:c/></root>', 0, FALSE, "ns:1"
);

var_dump(count(iterator_to_array($xml))); #int(3)
```

Comment: You would do great if you put this answer in php.net comments. Because there is no way to know about it. They didn't write anything... really.