# Add Child to XML Then Convert to CSV

Tags: php, xml, csv

Basically I have and XML file that I convert to CSV. This works great but I need to modify it to add the a same child to each of the XML parent elements before it converts it to CSV. I can only seem to get this to add to the first element and that's it. Is there a way to automatically add the same child to all the elements in the XML file?

Here is the XML

I have thousands of these.

```
<Item>
  <product>test</product>
  <Image>AC45G.jpg</Image>
</Item>
```

Here is my code

```
<?php

$new_xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

    $items = $new_xml->Item;

    $items->addChild('distributor', 'test');

function outputCSV($new_xml) {
    $outstream = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    $header=false;
    foreach($new_xml as $k=>$details){

        if(!$header){
            fputcsv($outstream,array_keys(get_object_vars($details)));
            $header=true;
        }
        fputcsv($outstream,get_object_vars($details));
    }
fclose($outstream);  
}


    header("Content-type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=lipseys.csv");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");

    outputCSV($new_xml);
?>
```

Comment: loop through $items and add it to all it's child elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using children() and foreach like this

```
<?php
foreach ($new_xml ->children() as $second_gen){
  $second_gen->addChild('distributor', 'test');
}
?>
```

Comment: But only maybe. In reality more important is the `foreach` and what `children()` is actually the default iteration, so you can spare that method call.

Answer (score 2):

By default, SimpleXML iterates over all child-elements of the SimpleXMLElement, so you need to `foreach` over the root-element (in the following example named `$element` instead of `$new_xml` as in your question) and then add the new child to each of it's children:

```
// iterate over child elements
foreach ($element as $child)
{
    $child->addChild('distributor', 'test');
}
```

The difference to the [`SimpleXMLElement::children()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.children) method is, that it will use the *namespace* of the *`SimpleXMLElement`* instead of the namespace given (optionally) in the `children()` method.

You can change the default namespace for iterating by specifying it when loading the file or instantiating the SimpleXMLElement. See as well: [What are the “$ns” and “$is_prefix” parameters about?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17258883/367456)

Usage Example:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

$items = $xml;

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item->addChild('distributor', 'test: ' . $item);
}

header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=lipseys.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$file = new SplFileObject("php://output");
foreach (new ValuesWithHeadersIterator($items) as $values) {
    $file->fputcsv($values);
}
```

Iterators used:

```
/**
 * Class ValuesIterator
 *
 * Treats each iteration as being (or being cast-able) to an array
 * of values.
 */
class ValuesIterator extends IteratorIterator
{
    public function current() {
        return (array) parent::current();
    }
}

/**
 * Class KeysIterator
 *
 * Returns keys instead of values per each ValuesIterator iteration.
 */
class KeysIterator extends ValuesIterator
{
    public function current() {
        return array_keys(parent::current());
    }
}


/**
 * Class ValuesWithHeadersIterator
 *
 * Same as ValuesIterator but expecting the first values
 * to have keys that can be used as headers
 */
class ValuesWithHeadersIterator extends IteratorIterator
{
    public function __construct(Traversable $iterator) {
        $headers = new LimitIterator(new KeysIterator($iterator), 0, 1);
        $values  = new ValuesIterator($iterator);
        $append  = new AppendIterator();
        $append->append($headers);
        $append->append($values);
        parent::__construct($append);
    }
}
```