# difference between getDocNamespaces and getNamespaces in SimpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, xml-namespaces

Two method of `SimpleXMLElement` are `getDocNamespaces` and `getNamespaces`. Both seems same to me, i tried the example of each other changing the method name but same result.

So can anyone explain it to me, what is the difference? Links from php.net [getNamespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php) [getdocnamespaces](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.getdocnamespaces.php)

Comment: You tried on an element where all namespaces are both defined as well as used. Most likely the root element and both methods are called with `TRUE` for the first, recursive parameter. That means all namespaces defined in the document are also used. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18354621/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getDocNamespaces() returns all namespaces declared in document; getNamespaces() returns only those namespaces that are **actually used** in the document.

Example #1 in the getNamespaces() doc page shows this with `xmlns:t="http://example.org/test"` defined, but not used.

Comment: Not in the document, but on the element.

Comment: Surely that depends whether you use the recursive switch or not?

Comment: I believe the recursive switch makes the functions look *downwards* but not *upwards*.

Comment: Probably so... generally I get my list of namespaces used when I'm at root level anyway, and work with schemas I'm familiar with; so I've never used the method when on a non-root node

Answer (score 2):

Actually those methods do two similar but different things. Both retrieve namespaces. Both can even do that *recursively*. Both can operate on elements.

The difference is to obtain namespaces *used* (`###:element`) with/on specific elements or *defined* (`xmlns:###="XMLNS-URI"`) on specific elements.

Some examples:

**`getNamespaces`** obtains *used* namespaces. E.g. if you've got a person element somewhere in the tree like:

```
...
   <p:person t:id="1">John Doe</p:person>
...
```

And you use

```
$sxe->person[0]->getNamespaces(TRUE);
```

on it, it will give you two namespaces, those two used on that element:

```
[p] => http://example.org/ns
[t] => http://example.org/test
```

**`getDocNamespaces`** in difference, when operating on that same element will give you the namespaces *defined*:

```
$sxe->person[0]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE);
```

As that element does not define any, the array is *empty*.

In difference to that, on a different, second person element:

```
...
    <p:person t:id="2" a:addr="123 Street" xmlns:a="http://example.org/addr">
        Susie Q. Public
    </p:person>
...

$sxe->person[1]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE);
```

will give you exactly one namespace because it's defined there:

```
[a] => http://example.org/addr
```

This should clarfiy it. You can permutate a bit through the diverse parameter combos, so here is some example script ([Demo](https://eval.in/44301)):

```
<?php
/**
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354621/367456
 */

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<people xmlns:p="http://example.org/ns" xmlns:t="http://example.org/test">
    <p:person t:id="1">John Doe</p:person>
    <p:person t:id="2" a:addr="123 Street" xmlns:a="http://example.org/addr">
        Susie Q. Public
    </p:person>
</people>
XML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml, 0, FALSE, 'http://example.org/ns');

echo 'person[0]->getNamespaces(TRUE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->person[0]->getNamespaces(TRUE)), "\n";

echo 'person[0]->getNamespaces(FALSE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->person[0]->getNamespaces(FALSE)), "\n";

echo 'person[0]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->person[0]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE)), "\n";

echo 'person[0]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->person[0]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE)), "\n";

echo 'person[1]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->person[1]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE)), "\n";

echo 'sxe->getNamespaces(FALSE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->getNamespaces(FALSE)), "\n";

echo 'sxe->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE)), "\n";

echo 'sxe->getDocNamespaces(FALSE, FALSE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->getDocNamespaces(FALSE, FALSE)), "\n";

echo 'sxe->getNamespaces(TRUE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->getNamespaces(TRUE)), "\n";

echo 'sxe->getDocNamespaces(TRUE): ', 
!print_r($sxe->getDocNamespaces(TRUE)), "\n";
```

Output:

```
person[0]->getNamespaces(TRUE): Array
(
    [p] => http://example.org/ns
    [t] => http://example.org/test
)

person[0]->getNamespaces(FALSE): Array
(
    [p] => http://example.org/ns
    [t] => http://example.org/test
)

person[0]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE): Array
(
    [p] => http://example.org/ns
    [t] => http://example.org/test
    [a] => http://example.org/addr
)

person[0]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE): Array
(
)

person[1]->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE): Array
(
    [a] => http://example.org/addr
)

sxe->getNamespaces(FALSE): Array
(
)

sxe->getDocNamespaces(TRUE, FALSE): Array
(
    [p] => http://example.org/ns
    [t] => http://example.org/test
    [a] => http://example.org/addr
)

sxe->getDocNamespaces(FALSE, FALSE): Array
(
    [p] => http://example.org/ns
    [t] => http://example.org/test
)

sxe->getNamespaces(TRUE): Array
(
    [p] => http://example.org/ns
    [t] => http://example.org/test
    [a] => http://example.org/addr
)

sxe->getDocNamespaces(TRUE): Array
(
    [p] => http://example.org/ns
    [t] => http://example.org/test
    [a] => http://example.org/addr
)
```

---

See as well:

- [What are the “$ns” and “$is_prefix” parameters about?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17258883/367456)